# IllegalStateException when adding & replacing Fragments; commit vs commitAllowingStateLoss

Tags: android, exception, android-fragments

It is rare that this happens, but occasionally my app will crash due to an IllegalStateException when adding and replacing fragments. Here is how I am doing it, I do so with an animation.

```
private void addFragmentReplace(int containerId, Fragment fragment) {
    // check if the fragment has been added already
    Fragment temp = mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragment.getTag());
    if (!Utils.checkIfNull(temp) && temp.isAdded()) {
        return;
    }

    // replace fragment and transition with animation
    mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.ui_slide_in_from_bottom_frag,
            R.anim.ui_slide_out_to_bottom_frag).replace(containerId, fragment).addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
}
```

I have researched into changing "commit()" to "commitAllowingStateLoss()" but is that really a solution? It will prevent the crashes, however, won't it cause other conflicts such as the fragment not displaying at times or other? Is the following an odd improvement to my above code snippet?

```
private void addFragmentReplace(int containerId, Fragment fragment) {
    // check if the fragment has been added already
    Fragment temp = mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragment.getTag());
    if (!Utils.checkIfNull(temp) && temp.isAdded()) {
        return;
    }

    // replace fragment and transition with animation
    try {
        mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.ui_slide_in_from_bottom_frag,
                R.anim.ui_slide_out_to_bottom_frag).replace(containerId, fragment).addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.ui_slide_in_from_bottom_frag,
                R.anim.ui_slide_out_to_bottom_frag).replace(containerId, fragment).addToBackStack(null)
                .commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance. My concerns come from the documentation for commitAllowingStateLoss() which reads

> Like {@link #commit} but allows the commit to be executed after an
>   activity's state is saved.  This is dangerous because the commit can
>   be lost if the activity needs to later be restored from its state, so
>   this should only be used for cases where it is okay for the UI state
>   to change unexpectedly on the user.

Some tips or advice on this would be appreciated. Thanks!